# Roughly context-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which definition of rough to choose? Could you tell me the correct definition that concords with the context of the definition of shack?

> Shack - a roughly built hut or cabin

- Rough - not finished decoratively
- Rough - not finished tidily
- Rough - lacking sophistication
- Rough - make uneven or ruffled
- Rough - lacking refinement

Comment: for building, we say shoddily built or poorly built or jerry-built **not** roughly. [also, goes with, not concords//concordar=goes with, or matches or agrees (for speaking).]

Comment: The first or the second one sounds appropriate.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh No, they don't work at all. A shack is a shack. To rough out a building means to build the basic structure but nothing else. And shacks are not relevant to "finishing decoratively".

Comment: Yes I agree @Lambie It doesn't sound very correct.. I have never seen what a __shack__ is, but judging by the pictures in Google, it seems like it is incompletely built or poorly built. However, I must say, that this is the definition given on Google (referring to your first comment).

Comment: @Lambie the definition comes from the Oxford dictionary and it's using **roughly built** to define a shack.

Comment: I'm baffled. What do you think is the difference between, say, ***lacking sophistication*** and ***lacking refinement***? And instead of wondering exactly which definition of "rough" is being used here, why not just look at definitions of "shack" in some ***other*** dictionaries? There are plenty to choose from online.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I would say it incorporates elements of all but one of those definitions:

- not finished decoratively
- not finished tidily
- lacking sophistication
- <s>make uneven or ruffled</s>
- lacking refinement

As the context appears to be a definition of the word "shack" it seems safe to assume it does not mean *unfinished* in the sense of being "incomplete". "Finished" can also mean decorated or furnished when applied to a building.

A "shack" is usually something deliberately built in a *simple* way - lacking refinement, which could incorporate a lack of decor or finishing of surfaces.